# Exercise question on expectation

Tags: probability

The question:

**A purse contains four coins each of which is either a one cent coin or a 2 cents coin. Find the expected value of a coin in that purse.**

My solution:

$\dfrac{3}{2}$

I assigned  $1$ and $2$ as random variables whose probabilities are $\dfrac{1}{2}$.
Subsequently,
$$1\cdot\frac{1}{2} + 2\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$$

Answer in the exercise book : **6** No explanation provided.

Could someone tell me if my answer is correct?And how is it $6$, if $6$ is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the given answer is wrong or you did not give the exact wording. I will assume the questions asked for the expected value of *the coins in that purse*.

Let us suppose that the coins have labels $1,2,3,4$. Let $X_i$ be the value of the $i$-th coin. You correctly found that for each $i$, we have $E(X_i)=\frac{3}{2}$.

But the total value of the coins is $X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4$. The exectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations, so we get $\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$.

More informally, each coin has expected value $\frac{3}{2}$, so the $4$ coins together have expected value $(4)\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$.

But with the wording *a coin*, your answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: "The expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations".Please explain this statement

Comment: Also the question asks "Find the expected value of **A** coin in that purse". So why did you consider all the 4 coins?

Comment: If $V$ is the random variable $X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4$, then $E(V)=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_4)$.  Yes, I mentioned in the answer that if it is *A* coin,, the answer is $\frac{3}{2}$, and that if it is THE coins, then the answer is $6$.

Answer (score 0):

The wording is a little wrong, The question is what is the Expected value of total coins in purse. The answer is $6$.

Total ways of having $4$ coins in a bag is $16$:

a. $6$ ways of two 1s and two 2s.

b. $4$ ways of three 1s and one of 2.

c. $4$ of three 2s and one of 1.

d. $1$ way for all 1s and similarly 1 of all 2s.

This amounts to

$$\frac{6}{16}\cdot(2+2+1+1) + \frac{4}{16}\cdot(1+1+1+2)$$

and so on for all five terms. Summing them up using $E(x) = \Sigma(P(X_{i})\cdot X_{i})$, you get $6$.